# How to get HIT IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am looking to update the reward price via command line tools. I made the properties file, and now I just need to make a success file to record the HIT ID to use.

Is there a command I can run to view all HIT IDs? I cannot find the HIT in the mturk.com user interface either.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all of your HITs in the web interface on the ["Manage HITs Individually" page](https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs?). The HITIds are not displayed, but they are embedded in the links to perform various actions on each HIT (such as Download Results or Add Time, etc.).

Via the API, you can use [SearchHITs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SearchHITsOperation.html) to retrieve all of your HITs. This API endpoint is not exposed via the command line tools, however.